# better way to get results from multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

what i want to do is be able to call a function with multiple threads and get their results.

i have the following code:

(it is an example, the actual code doesn't simply convert str to int)

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import Queue

#an example - actual code connects to a server
def str_to_int(arg, queue):
    result = 0
    result = int(arg)
    #sleep to check that they happen at once.
    time.sleep(10)
    queue.put(result)

def combine():
    q1 = Queue.Queue()
    q2 = Queue.Queue()
    q3 = Queue.Queue()

    t1 = Thread(target = str_to_int, args=("111", q1))
    t2 = Thread(target = str_to_int, args=("222", q2))
    t3 = Thread(target = str_to_int, args=("333", q3))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()

    return (q1.get(),q2.get(),q3.get())

print combine()
```

this code works. and i get the expected results:

```
>>> 
(111, 222, 333)
```

however, there must be a better way to do this.
i plan on having many more threads than 3, but even if i was only staying with 3 - it seems very ugly.

**EDIT:** i need to be able to know which result came from which thread (ie: from which parameters/arguments that i gave the function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some advices:

1. `Queue`'s are thread-safe, so use 1 queue to pass results.
2. You can create all threads in a cycle and use your queue to pass results. You don't need to have explicit variable for each thread.

So here's what your code might look like:

```
def str_to_int(arg, queue):
    result = int(arg)
    queue.put({arg: result})

def combine():
    arguments = ('111', '222', '333')
    q = Queue.Queue()
    threads = []

    for argument in arguments:
        t = Thread(target=str_to_int, args=(argument, q))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    return [q.get() for _ in xrange(len(arguments))]
```

Comment: You may want to move the t.join()'s into their own loop, otherwise the threads will run serially.

Comment: this does not work. the threads are running after eachother not simultaneously, as @AustinPhillips said.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, threads has to be joined in a separate loop, because join causes main thread blocking.

Comment: hmm - sorry i marked it as accepted, but then i realized this causes a problem for me. how to i now get the different results and be able to know which one i am working on?

Comment: You can put not only result into queue, but something that will point to arguments, e.g. queue.put({argument: resut}) in your worker function. I've updated post with modified str_to_int function

Comment: so then i could read all of the q.get() into a dictionary, and then i could access the results for each function by the argument?

Comment: It's a bad idea to read all results:values into one dictionary unless you know that your arguments are repeating, but in general yes, you can read all queue and build a dictionary of it

Comment: You could pass a unique thread number as part of the args when invoking the thread, which would be posted to the result queue.  Once you have the results you can order them according to thread number of you need to.

Answer (score 0):

> i need to be able to know which result came from which thread (ie: from which parameters/arguments that i gave the function)

I use a function like this to keep track of which result came from which task:

```py
from threading import Thread
import typing

def run_together(tasks: typing.Dict[typing.Hashable, tuple],
                 except_errors: tuple = None) -> dict:
    """
    :param tasks: a dict of task keys matched to a tuple of callable and its arguments
    <pre>tasks = {'task1': (add, 1, 2), 'task2': (add, 3, 4)}</pre>

    :param except_errors: a tuple of errors that should be catched. Defaults to all errors 
    :return: a dictionary of results with the same keys as `tasks` parameter
    <pre>results = {'task1': 3, 'task2': 7}</pre>
    """
    # catch all exceptions by default
    if not except_errors:
        except_errors = (Exception,)
    threads = []
    results = dict()

    def save_results(f, key):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            except except_errors as e:
                result = e
            results[key] = result

        return wrapped

    for key, (func, *args) in tasks.items():
        thread = Thread(
            target=save_results(func, key),
            args=args
        )
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    return results
```

`tasks` parameter is a dictionary of keys and a tuple of callable with its arguments. You can modify `save` decorator to return a `list` if you want.

So you can do:

```py
def add(first, second):
    return first + second

tasks = {f'result:{n}': (add, n, 1) for n in range(4)}
results = run_together(tasks)
print(results)
```

which gives:

```py
{'result:0': 1, 'result:1': 2, 'result:2': 3, 'result:3': 4}
```